# URL Rewrite multilanguage site

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I have a multilanguage website made using wordpress running on apache 2.2. The url structure is www.domain.it for italian and www.domain.it/?lang=es for (for example) spanish.
My client owns also www.domain.es. My goal is to have users write www.domain.es and be redirected to www.domain.it/?lang=es
this is my htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.es$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://www.domain.it/$1/?lang=es [QSA]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

the last four rows are for wordpress to provide index.php in some specific cases. The other two are mine to achive the goal. What I get now is a 302 page telling me that the document has moved (it says again to www.domain.es. If I add R=301 I get no more luck. 
What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me to stop banging my head around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want it to redirect? Or just handle the rewriting internally somehow?

You may need the `L` flag to tell it to stop trying to do anything else and just do that redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.es$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.it/$1/?lang=es [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: I want to redirect them to the new url. So that the browser gets them the site with the chosen language.

Comment: Adding L and R=301 it works like a charm. Thank you! I was using just QSA and R=301 and it didn't!